# MySQL - Nonsense Syntax Errors

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new to programming, and cannot understand the syntax errors that I'm getting.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS donutsrus;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DONUT (
    Donut_ID            INT             NOT NULL, UNIQUE
    Donut_Name          VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL, UNIQUE
    Description         VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL, UNIQUE
    Unit_Price          NUMERIC (4,2)   NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (Donut_ID));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SALES_ORDER (
    Sales_Order_ID      INT             NOT NULL, UNIQUE
    Sales_Order_Date    DATE            NOT NULL
    Sales_Order_Notes   VARCHAR (100)
    Customer_ID         INT             NOT NULL, UNIQUE
    PRIMARY KEY (Sales_Order_ID)
    FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (
    Customer_ID         INT             NOT NULL, UNIQUE
    Last_Name           VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL
    First_Name          VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL
    Address             VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL
    Apt                 VARCHAR (5)
    City                VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL
    State               CHAR (2)        NOT NULL
    Zip                 NUMBER (5)      NOT NULL
    Home_Phone          NUMBER (10)
    Mobile_Phone        NUMBER (10)
    Other_Phone         NUMBER (10)
    PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDER_LINE_ITEM (
    Donut_ID            INT             NOT NULL, UNIQUE
    Sales_Order_ID      INT             NOT NULL, UNIQUE
    Quantity            INT             NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (Donut_ID, Sales_Order_ID)
    FOREIGN KEY (Donut_ID, Sales_Order_ID));
```

On the `Donut` table, I get `Syntax error: extraneous input found - expected 'opening parenthesis'`, at the `VARCHAR` after `Donut_Name`. At the closing paren after the succeeding 20, I get `Syntax error: extraneous input found - expected 'closing parenthesis'`.

On the `Order Line Item` table I get, `Syntax Error: 'INT' (int) is not valid input at this position`, after the `Sales_Order_ID`. I also don't understand why it's okay on other lines of code, but not this one.

Comment: wow, `non sense syntax error`? - be respectful on the community

Comment: To add to that , should separate the definitions of the columns.

Comment: If you have read the MySQL documentation properly, you'll know that your got the syntax wrong, not the `nonsense syntax error`, more like `nonsense statement`.

Comment: These are fair statements. I'll do better to remember that there wouldn't be an error if I'd written it correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the commas before `UNIQUE` are wrong. Commas are used to separate the columns, not to separate options for a specific column.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DONUT (
    Donut_ID            INT             NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Donut_Name          VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Description         VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Unit_Price          NUMERIC (4,2)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Donut_ID));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (
    Customer_ID         INT             NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Last_Name           VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL,
    First_Name          VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL,
    Address             VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    Apt                 VARCHAR (5),
    City                VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL,
    State               CHAR (2)        NOT NULL,
    Zip                 NUMBER (5)      NOT NULL,
    Home_Phone          NUMBER (10),
    Mobile_Phone        NUMBER (10),
    Other_Phone         NUMBER (10),
    PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SALES_ORDER (
    Sales_Order_ID      INT             NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Sales_Order_Date    DATE            NOT NULL,
    Sales_Order_Notes   VARCHAR (100),
    Customer_ID         INT             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Sales_Order_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (Customer_ID));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDER_LINE_ITEM (
    Donut_ID            INT             NOT NULL,
    Sales_Order_ID      INT             NOT NULL,
    Quantity            INT             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Donut_ID, Sales_Order_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Donut_ID) REFERENCES DONUT (Donut_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Sales_Order_ID) REFERENCES SALES_ORDER (Sales_Order_ID));
```

BTW, the `UNIQUE` option is not necessary for primary keys, they're automatically made unique. And in `ORDER_LINE_ITEM`, if the primary key is `(Donut_ID, Sales_Order_ID)` you probably don't want to make each of those columns unique by themselves. This prevents the same donut from being in multiple orders, or an order having more than one donut type. Similarly, `Customer_ID` should not be unique in `SALES_ORDER`; a customer can obviously have more than one order.

Your `FOREIGN KEY` lines were missing the references of the foreign keys. And the tables with the foreign keys need to be created after the tables they reference, so I moved `SALES_ORDER` down to after `CUSTOMER`.

Comment: Don't forget the FOREIGN KEYs don't specify what they reference; which brings me to `EXISTS ORDER_LINE_ITEM`'s FK being eventual gibberish.

Comment: Good catch I added those fixes.

Comment: `Customer_ID` beeing UNIQUE in `SALES_ORDER` looks also like a bad business plan :-)